# Mark question as duplicate if the answer accidentally solves my question?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have asked this question: [How does TypeScript Record Type result in a index type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57557734/how-does-typescript-record-type-result-in-a-index-type)

Someone proposed another question as duplicate: [Difference between index signature and Record for empty object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54100025/difference-between-index-signature-and-record-for-empty-object)

I have accepted it, because it has an excellent, in depth answer, which also answers my question.

But I'm not sure if it was the correct action though, since the question is a different one. The other question is about the difference of 2 types, while I'm asking about compiler specifics.

Comment: The question is, will people coming to your question, have their question answered by going to that other question?

Comment: Also, if that solves your problem which you posted then it was closed correctly. So it will solve the problem of future visitors too who are having the same problem as you are having

Comment: @KevinB Yes, if that answer stays the same future visitors will have their question answered.

Comment: Will any answer to the other question also answer yours?

Comment: If all answers on the dupe target is correct to you answer then blindly dupe flag. If not please specify somewhere witch answer is the one fixing the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Yes** - if an answer-post on different question solve your problem (even if it a different question but the explanation is the same) you should mark it as duplicate and you shouldn't delete it.

Consider other user encounter the same problem as yours. They will search and find your question and not the other one as the question is different - but they still want to have an answer, right?

So, what should you do? instead of copy/narrow the good explanation on other post and re-post it (which you shouldn't do) just mark it as duplicate. future user will just hit the link and find the answer well explained.

Bottom line - you did well!